# Why GitHub pages on [username].github.io won't show?

Tags: github, github-pages

I created repo [username].github.io, pushed first commit in gh-pages branch, have been waiting for 30 mins (GitHub says, it shouldn't take more than 10) and got 404 page trying to load my page.
Checked out with different browsers, results are the same.

Here's the way how I've done it:

```
$ git clone http://github.com/RedCorbie/RedCorbie.github.io
$ git add index.html 
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
$ git branch gh-pages
$ git push origin gh-pages
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation mentions](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator/):

> If you generated a User Pages site, the code lives in the `master` branch instead of the `gh-pages` branch.

In your case, you might want to create and push a master branch.

```
git checkout -b master
git push -u origin master
```

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

That means project pages can now *also* live on `master`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.  A lot of people (me included) don't realize the subtle difference between project pages and user pages.