# Deploy path doesn't work for Git Deploy Method in middleman-deploy

Tags: ruby, git, deployment, middleman

I am using [middleman-blog](https://github.com/middleman/middleman-blog) and [middleman-deploy](https://github.com/middleman-contrib/middleman-deploy).

What I would like to do, is within the branch I am deploying to, I want the static files to be deployed to a subfolder within the repo (i.e. not the root folder).

I tried doing this in my `config.rb`:

```
activate :deploy do |deploy|
  deploy.build_before = true
  deploy.deploy_method = :git
  deploy.branch = 'gh-pages-2'
  deploy.remote = 'github'
  deploy.path = 'blog'
end
```

But that doesn't work, it still deploys to the root directory. In fact, it doesn't even create the `/blog` folder I am looking for.

When I visit the config settings locally, these are the settings I see under `:deploy`:

```
:deploy
   :branch = "gh-pages"
   :build_before = true
   :clean = false
   :commit_message = nil
   :deploy_method = :git
   :flags = nil
   :host = nil
   :password = nil
   :path = "blog"
   :port = 22
   :remote = "github"
   :strategy = :force_push
   :user = nil
```

This indicates to me that the path attribute is being set correctly.

I also tried doing `deploy.path = '/blog'` and that still doesn't work.

So how can I get this to deploy to `\blog\` subfolder within my repo rather than the root directory?

The versions of the different gems are as follows:

```
middleman (4.1.10)
middleman-blog (4.0.1)
middleman-cli (4.1.10)
middleman-deploy (2.0.0.pre.alpha)
```

**Note:** I am purposely using `gh-pages-2` because I don't want to overwrite my current `gh-pages` without being certain that it will deploy to the correct subfolder.

Comment: https://github.com/middleman-contrib/middleman-deploy/issues/114 ould not help? (like https://github.com/middleman-contrib/middleman-deploy/issues/114#issuecomment-175902823). Plus, you also have now another approach of using only one branch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27202100/6309

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing you could do is write an extension with an after build step: https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/custom-extensions/#after_build. That way you move the files during your build process and middleman-deploy just can push the whole build folder.

Answer (score 0):

If the root of your site is also deployed on **Github Pages** you can create another repo called `blog` and deploy your middleman site there. Then by enabling GitHub Pages for the blog repo, you will actually have it deployed on `yoursite.com/blog`.

It is not the techiest solution you 'd expect but it works well for me